# What is happenning with that single hydrogen in Phosphorous acid?

Tags: acid-base, molecular-structure

As an oxyacid, Phosphorous acid intuitively should have the structure

[image]

since the hydrogens should be on the oxygens.

However, the major form of this acid is actually

[image]

with the hydrogen attached to the phosphorous.

My question is, what fundamentally causes the second form to be more stable than the first?

Comment: Did you see and read the English article in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphorous_acid)?

Comment: @Buttonwood yes, I obviously did, and there was no information that answered my question as to *why* the H is bonded to P and not O. Or else I wouldn't be asking this question here lol

Comment: Related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/127414/why-does-noh3-not-exist https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/85253/phosphorous-acid-vs-phosphonic-acid

Comment: Is it bond energies? Other tautomeric equilibria are driven significantly by bond enthalpies